# Zend Framework - Prevent a model from running

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to be able to make a security check every time my models run. If the check fails, then I want to prevent the query to execute. I have already created a MyWork_Model_Base that extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and my models then extend the MyWork_Model_Base. I think I should perform this check in the init(); but I how do I prevent the model from running if it fails?

Thanks

Comment: You can redirect user, throw/call error or just exit script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already class for such purposes - Zend_Acl

You can create resources (guest, authorized-users, admin), roles (guest, authorized-user, admin) and create "acl tables".

```
<?php
  $acl = new Zend_Acl();
?>
```

After creating all the necessery rules, you can check is user is allowed to run model with such code:

```
<?php
   if ($acl->isAllowed('admin','admin-news','create')
?>
```

Which is checking is user with role 'admin' is allowed 'create' in resource 'admin-news'.
As resource you can join module and controller and action would be last parameter.

Check should be provided in Controller_Plugin where you can change run action.